# Webpacker fails to compile React code: Invalid configuration object

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpacker

I'm trying to update a working Rails 5/React app (used webpack through npm) to Rails 6.  I did this by starting creating a new rails app with webpacker=rails so that (in theory) it would make things easier on me.  I've copied over all of the relevant code, and just can't get webpacker to compile my React code.

My relevant file structure is:

```
Project
   |- app
       |- javascript
              |- packs
                   |- reactFrontend
                           |- /components, /actions, etc.
                   |- application.js
                   |- ProjectEntry.jsx
```

Running bin/webpack-dev-server results in the error:

```
✖ ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry should be one of these:
   function | object { <key>: non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string | [non-empty string]
   -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
   Details:
    * configuration.entry['reactFrontend/components/dropdown_modal/dropdown_modal'] should be a string.
      -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
    * configuration.entry['reactFrontend/components/dropdown_modal/dropdown_modal'] should be an array:
      [non-empty string]
      -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings
    * configuration.entry['reactFrontend/components/dropdown_modal/dropdown_modal'] should be one of these:
      [non-empty string]
      -> All modules are loaded upon startup. The last one is exported.
    * configuration.entry['reactFrontend/components/dropdown_modal/dropdown_modal'] should be one of these:
      non-empty string | [non-empty string]
      -> An entry point with name
```

I've seen a few posts here and elsewhere with the same general error, but unfortunately, their solutions didn't quite do it for me.  The modal component that it references works perfectly fine in the older version of the app.
One thing I did try was putting my 'reactFrontend' folder outside in /javascript but outside /packs, and webpacker successfully compiles (just without all of my React code, of course), so it's finding the packs folder successfully.

My webpacker.yml file, in case that helps:

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: ['app/javascript/packs/reactFrontend']  <-- have tried with and without
```

All I can get to render is my root.html.erb which is in app/views/static_pages

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I needed two javascript_pack_tag's: one for application.js, and the other for my React entry file.